# Disable evil-mode in eshell

Tags: evil, window, eshell

I have disabled evil-mode in eshell by `(evil-set-initial-state 'eshell-mode 'emacs)` but when I switch windows(accidentally) using `C-w k` from eshell, evil-mode gets enabled.

How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I've made the same kind of customization and have yet to run into what you've described. Chances are it's your configuration doing weird things (yes, Spacemacs and Doom count).

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've made changes to it.